# Ad placement optimization for lead marketplace

Tags: python, optimization

I'm looking for suggestions for ad placement optimization problem. Description is below.

> There exists a lead marketplace with 4 entities.
>
> 1. Marketplace M
> 2. Individuals I
> 3. Publishers P
> 4. Advertisers A
>
> An Individual I will generate a lead via a Publisher P.There are P
> publishers sending leads to the Marketplace M.There are A advertisers
> offering their services on marketplace M. Each Advertiser Ai has x Ads
> that are active at any one time denoted, Aix.There are n ad slots
> available to display ads from choices of Aix to each lead. Each slot
> has a different probability of being clicked.Each ad Aix has two
> performance variables - probability of being clicked and revenue
> generated to marketplace M if the ad is clicked, i.e. some ads pay
> more than others and do so more often than others. The goal is to
> maximize revenue for marketplace M.

I initially considered bandits, but I don't think that will work because bandits assume a fixed payout with variable payout rate. In our case, we have variable payout rate but also variable payout.

Any suggestions to research papers or specific algorithms would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bandits do not assume fixed payouts. Bernoulli bandits assume that the rewards are binary, but there are also bandit algorithms for non-binary rewards, for example, they can be continuous (see e.g. [Bonald, 2018](https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/bonald/documents/bandit.pdf)). In the generic formulation of the multi-armed bandit problem, you have a set of arms $a \in A$ that generate rewards $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with probabilities $p(r|a)$. We can define expectation

$$
q(a) = E[r|a]
$$

in such a case, the best action is the one that maximizes the expected reward

$$
a^\star = \underset{a \in A}{\operatorname{arg\max}} \; q(a)
$$

where the expected reward per action is

$$
q^\star = \underset{a \in A}{\max} \; q(a)
$$

and we aim to maximize the cumulative reward over time $\sum_t r_t$. For such a problem, you wouldn't use the Bernoulli bandit, but another formulation that allows for non-binary rewards. The common choice is using Gaussian distributions, because of mathematical convenience (easy to update thanks to [conjugacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution), easy to calculate expectations, etc).

If variable payout rates are an issue for you, you can always play the arm for a fixed amount of time and then look at the total collected rewards in the time window. This would make the results collected for each arm would be comparable.

*Answering the comment:* If you are not limited to pulling one arm at a time, it's still doable, however, it is not the classical multi-armed anymore, but a *budget allocation problem*. You can pull multiple arms, doing a Bayesian update of the rewards per each arm. To allocate the resources, you can do it proportionally to the expected rewards or have other strategies depending on the details of the problem. It's a slightly different problem, as you are optimizing the overall expected reward that needs to account for how much do you exploit each of the arms.

Comment: ah interesting. I did not know that. Thank you. What about the situation where we are pulling multiple arms at once - one for each of the ad slots?

Comment: @fcol you can use the same Bayesian updating for each arm, but in such case, it's not the simple multi-arm bandit but a different problem.